# What is wrong with my actionListener call

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, paintcomponent

I am getting an error: constructor RedListener in class RedListener cannot be applied to given types;
            jrbRed.addActionListener(new RedListener(canvas, canvas2));

I am getting one for each of the listeners. The program is supposed to be a traffic light that when I click on a radio button that light "lights" up. if its not clicked then its just supposed to be outlined in the color

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;



public class Lab4Frame extends JFrame {
    //public boolean red, yellow, green;
    Lab4Frame(){
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setTitle("Lab 4 - Application #1");
        Lab4Panel p = new Lab4Panel();
        Lab4RadioButtonPanel p2 = new Lab4RadioButtonPanel();
        add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

            Lab4Frame frame = new Lab4Frame();
            frame.setTitle("Lab4 Application # 1");
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(600, 600);
            frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}

class Lab4RadioButtonPanel extends JPanel {
        Lab4Panel canvas = new Lab4Panel();
        Lab4RadioButtonPanel canvas2 = new Lab4RadioButtonPanel();
    public Lab4RadioButtonPanel() {
        boolean red, green, yellow;



        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JRadioButton jrbRed = new JRadioButton("Red", true);
        JRadioButton jrbYellow = new JRadioButton("Yellow");
        JRadioButton jrbGreen = new JRadioButton("Green");

        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(jrbRed);
        group.add(jrbYellow);
        group.add(jrbGreen);

        this.add(jrbRed);
        this.add(jrbYellow);
        this.add(jrbGreen);

        jrbRed.addActionListener(new RedListener(canvas, canvas2));
        jrbYellow.addActionListener(new YellowListener(canvas, canvas2));
        jrbGreen.addActionListener(new GreenListener(canvas, canvas2));

    }
}










class Lab4Panel extends JPanel{


    public Lab4Panel(){}



    boolean red, green, yellow;
    int radius = 5;
    int x = -1;
    int y = -1;

    public void setRed(){
        red = true;
        repaint();
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        if (x<0 || y<0) {
            x = getWidth() / 2 - radius;
            y = getHeight() / 2 - radius;
        }
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawRect(x - 10,y - 90, 40, 120);
        g.drawOval(x,y - 80, 4 * radius, 4 * radius);
        g.drawOval(x,y - 40, 4 * radius, 4 * radius);
        g.drawOval(x,y, 4 * radius, 4 * radius);
        g.drawRect(x - 5,y - 90, 40, 120);

        if(red){
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillOval(x,y - 80, 4 * radius, 4 * radius);
            repaint();
        }

        else if (yellow){
            g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g.fillOval(x,y - 40, 4 * radius, 4 * radius);
            repaint();
        }

        if(green){
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillOval(x,y, 4 * radius, 4 * radius);
            repaint();
        }

    }


}


class RedListener implements ActionListener{
    private Lab4RadioButtonPanel canvas;
    private Lab4Panel canvas2;

    RedListener(Lab4RadioButtonPanel canvas, Lab4Panel canvas2) {
     this.canvas = canvas;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        canvas2.setRed();
    }
}

class YellowListener implements ActionListener{
    private Lab4RadioButtonPanel canvas;
    private Lab4Panel canvas2;

    YellowListener(Lab4RadioButtonPanel canvas, Lab4Panel canvas2) {
     this.canvas = canvas;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        canvas2.setRed();
    }
}

class GreenListener implements ActionListener{
    private Lab4RadioButtonPanel canvas;
    private Lab4Panel canvas2;

    GreenListener(Lab4RadioButtonPanel canvas, Lab4Panel canvas2) {
     this.canvas = canvas;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        canvas2.setRed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this:

```
Lab4Panel canvas = new Lab4Panel();
Lab4RadioButtonPanel canvas2 = new Lab4RadioButtonPanel();
```

and this:

```
jrbRed.addActionListener(new RedListener(canvas, canvas2));
```

but your constructor is this:

```
RedListener(Lab4RadioButtonPanel canvas, Lab4Panel canvas2)
```

You probably want:

```
jrbRed.addActionListener(new RedListener(canvas2, canvas));
```

i.e. you reversed the order of parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Compare the constructor parameters

```
RedListener(Lab4RadioButtonPanel canvas, Lab4Panel canvas2) {...}
```

to the arguments that you're passing it

```
Lab4Panel canvas = new Lab4Panel();
Lab4RadioButtonPanel canvas2 = new Lab4RadioButtonPanel();
...
jrbRed.addActionListener(new RedListener(canvas, canvas2));
```

There is absolutely no reason why you shouldn't have been able to debug this problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I am a student still learning this stuff. I have been looking at the textpad compiler for 20 minutes trying to figure out what I did wrong.

Comment: @user512915, Familiarize yourself with a more sophisticated, professional IDE (e.g. Eclipse, NetBeans, and etc.). These compilers would have reduced those 20 minutes of pointless debugging to a few nanoseconds. ;]

Comment: We are not allowed to use IDE's in class. I forgot to put that at the top sorry.

Comment: @user512915, Your choice of variable names helped confuse you. But more importantly: grow a thicker skin.

Comment: @user512915, What sort of backward university are you attending?